How to get the "HostElementID" for an asset to use in the Stream upload csv?
I want to upload a list of streams via the batch upload in Tandem and I'd like to include the Host Element. Unfortunately, using the Revit Internal ElementId doesn't work as the Element ID.
How do you obtain the element ID, is it possible to do in the platform?
If not, is there a process for getting it via the API?

in case you want to link stream to host using CSV import you also need to provide values for HostModelID and HostElementID columns. HostModelId is internal URN of the model. HostElementID is unique key of the element. Easiest way to get these values is to export elements from Inventory panel. The values are available under DtModelId, k columns - last columns from the output file.
In case you would like to do this using API you can use this example as starting point.

Thank you that works a treat. I wasn't aware you could get that information from the Inventory Download. It also makes it difficult that the columns are named differently. But all good once you know!
